# How come my container's are displaying a white background?

Tags: html, css, containers, 960.gs

I'm using the [Nathan Smith Grid System](http://960.gs/) and everything I wrap with the "container_12" class has a white background. What I want is it to be transparent.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/JordanSimps/RZvxn/1/

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Beginning of the blue top header -->
        <div class="top-header-wrap">
            <div class="container_12">
                <div class="top-header">
                    <div class="grid_2">
                        <img class="hover" src="http://www.dubstepcast.com/images/phone.png" />&nbsp;&nbsp; (586) 997-9490
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid_3">
                        <img src="http://www.dubstepcast.com/images/mail.png" />&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="mailto:jordansimps@me.com" alt="E-Mail us">info@experienceheritage.org</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="social">
                        <div class="grid_7">
                            <ul>
                                <li id="twitter"><a href="1.html"><img id="twitter" src="http://www.dubstepcast.com/images/twitter.png" /></a></li>
                                <li id="pinterest"><a href="1.html"><img id="pinterest" src="http://www.dubstepcast.com/images/pinterest.png" /></a></li>
                                <li id="facebook"><a href="1.html"><img id="facebook" src="http://www.dubstepcast.com/images/facebook.png" /></a></li>
                                <li id="google"><a href="1.html"><img id="google" src="http://www.dubstepcast.com/images/google.png" /></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of the blue top header -->

        <!-- Beginning of the second header - Logo & Navigation buttons -->    
        <div class="container_12">
            <div class="bottom-header">
                <!-- LOGO BEGINS HERE -->
                <div class="grid_2">
                    <p><img class="logo" src="http://www.dubstepcast.com/images/logo2.png" /></p>
                </div>
                <!-- LOGO ENDS HERE -->

                <!-- NAVIGATION BUTTONS BEGIN HERE -->
                <div class="grid_8 prefix_2">
                <ul class='navbar navbar-horizontal'>
                    <a href="#" id="panel-1" class="drop-shadow raised">
                        Home
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" id="panel-2">
                        FAQ's
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" id="panel-3">
                        Invite
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" id="panel-4">
                        Contact
                    </a>
                </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- NAVIGATION BUTTONS END HERE -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of the second header - Logo & Navigation buttons -->
```

**CSS:**

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    background-image: url('http://www.dubstepcast.com/images/bg.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    border: 1px solid #666;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
}


/* HEADER */

/* TOP HEADER */
.top-header {
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #11A1B1;
    height: 43px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

    .top-header a {
        color: #FFF;
        font-family: "Helvetica";
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

        .top-header a:hover {
            color: #D3582D;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

.top-header-wrap {
    border-top: solid 3px #32BED0;
    background: #11A1B1;
    height: 58px;
}

/* SOCIAL ICONS */
#social {
    height: 35px;
}

#social li {
    display: inline;
}

/* TWITTER */
#social ul #twitter a { 
    background-image: url('http://www.dubstepcast.com/images/twitter.png');
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
}

#social ul #twitter a:hover {
    background-image: url('http://www.dubstepcast.com/images/twitter.png');
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
}

/* PINTEREST */
#social ul #pinterest a { 
    background-image: url('http://www.dubstepcast.com/images/pinterest.png');
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
}

#social ul #pinterest a:hover {
    background-image: url('http://www.dubstepcast.com/images/pinterest_active.png');
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
}

/* FACEBOOK */
#social {
    text-align: right;
}

#social ul #facebook a { 
    background-image: url('http://www.dubstepcast.com/images/facebook.png');
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
}

#social ul #facebook a:hover {
    background-image: url('http://www.dubstepcast.com/images/facebook_active.png');
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
}

/* GOOGLE */
#social ul #google a { 
    background-image: url('http://www.dubstepcast.com/images/google.png');
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
}

#social ul #google a:hover {
    background-image: url('http://www.dubstepcast.com/images/google_active.png');
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
}

/* BOTTOM HEADER */
.bottom-header {
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 155px;
}

.bottom-header img {
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.drop-shadow {
            position:relative;
            float:left;
            width:40%;
            padding:1em;
            margin:2em 10px 4em;
            background:#fff;
            -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
               -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
                    box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
        }

        .drop-shadow:before,
        .drop-shadow:after {
            content:"";
            position:absolute;
            z-index:-2;
        }

        .drop-shadow p {
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight:bold;
        }


/*
 *  Kwicks: Sexy Sliding Panels for jQuery - v2.1.0
 *  http://devsmash.com/projects/navbar
 *
 *  Copyright 2013 Jeremy Martin (jmar777)
 *  Contributors: Duke Speer (Duke3D)
 *  Released under the MIT license
 *  http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */
.navbar {
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    margin: 55px 0 0 25px;
    padding: 0;
}

    .navbar > a {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-family: "Helvetica";
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
        -o-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -8px rgba(62, 62, 62, 0.5), 0 1px 4px rgba(62, 62, 62, 0.2), 0 0 40px rgba(62, 62, 62, 0) inset;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -8px rgba(62, 62, 62, 0.5), 0 1px 4px rgba(62, 62, 62, 0.2), 0 0 40px rgba(62, 62, 62, 0) inset;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -8px rgba(62, 62, 62, 0.5), 0 1px 4px rgba(62, 62, 62, 0.2), 0 0 40px rgba(62, 62, 62, 0) inset;
        font-size: 16px;
        width: 125px;
        height: 18px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 25px 0 30px 0;
    }

    .navbar > a p {
        font-family: "Helvetica";
        font-weight: lighter;
        color: #11A1B1;
        margin-top: 4px;
        font-size: 10px;
        letter-spacing: normal;
    }

    .navbar > a:hover p {
        color: #11A1B1;
    }

    .navbar > a:hover {
        color: #D3582D;
    }

    .navbar > * {
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .navbar.navbar-processed > * {
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .navbar-horizontal > * {
        float: left;
    }

    .navbar-horizontal > :first-child {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    .navbar-vertical > :first-child {
        margin-top: 0;
    }

#panel-1 {
    background-color: #464646;
    border-top: solid 3px #11A1B1;
}

#panel-2 {
    background-color: #464646;
    border-top: solid 3px #11A1B1;
}

#panel-3 {
    background-color: #464646;
    border-top: solid 3px #11A1B1;
}

#panel-4 {
    background-color: #464646;
    border-top: solid 3px #11A1B1;
}

/* GIVES THE DROP-SHADOW ON THE NAVIGATION BUTTONS MORE OF A REALISTIC LOOK */
.drop-shadow {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 2em 10px 4em;
    background: #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}

    .drop-shadow:before, .drop-shadow:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -2;
    }

    .drop-shadow p {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your jsfiddle the following CSS rules are being applied to container_12 in the demo.css file

```
.container_12, .container_16, .container_24 {
    background-color: #fff; /* Makes the background white */
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

So you can either remove these or overwrite them with

```
.container_12 {
    background: none
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I missed that -_-.

Answer (score 0):

add this to `css`

```
.container_12{
background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have background-color: #fff; set in demo.css

Change it to background-color: transparent;

Answer (score 0):

as per firebug, this is line 2 of demo.css

```
.container_12, .container_16, .container_24 {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

so use

```
#div.container_12 {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

to override it with greater specificity